# Django all-auth: Doesn't show First name and Last name while signing up for new accout

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using Django-all auth for creating user accounts. I want to get First name, Last name, Email, and Password while signing up. But Sign up page Doesn't show First name and Last name. Sign up page showing only Email and Password. Could someone help me with that? Please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks!

Models.py

```
    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        # add additional fields in here
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

Forms.py

```
    class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

        class Meta(UserCreationForm):
            model = CustomUser
            fields = ('email','first_name','last_name')
```

Signup.html

```
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: That's because you set `blank=True`.

Comment: You furthermore should *not* subclass `Meta` from `UserCreationForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Docs](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/account/configuration.html), you can override the the signup form. The default values are:

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
            'add_email': 'allauth.account.forms.AddEmailForm'
            'change_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ChangePasswordForm'
            'disconnect': 'allauth.socialaccount.forms.DisconnectForm'
            'login': 'allauth.account.forms.LoginForm'
            'reset_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordForm'
            'reset_password_from_key': 'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordKeyForm'
            'set_password': 'allauth.account.forms.SetPasswordForm'
            'signup': 'allauth.account.forms.SignupForm'
            'signup': 'allauth.socialaccount.forms.SignupForm'
}
```

It can be done by just adding `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'myapp.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'}` to your **settings.py**.

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems here. First of all, I'm not sure if you want to set [**`blank=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank), since that means that by default Django will hide these fields from editing. You might even not want to make these [**`null=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) either, since that means the users are *not* required to fill these in. Your probably do not want that:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

As for the form, you should *not* subclass `Meta` from the `UserCreationForm` itself. Perhaps you want to subclass it from the `UserCreationForm.Meta`:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email','first_name','last_name')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed as you suggested but it didn't work. Sign up page doesn't show the fields first_name and last_name.

Comment: @sreekanthkura7: are you sure you use the correct form?

Comment: I am using Django-allauth libray, I use below settings for this.
    # add customUser model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @sreekanthkura7: but where do you specify that it should use your `CustomUserCreationForm` here?

Comment: Thats's a good question. Do you know where do I do that in django-allauth? Thanks!

Comment: @sreekanthkura7: you will need to specify that in your `urls.py`, like in `SignupView.as_view(form_class=CustomUserCreationForm)`.

Comment: I added ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = "users.forms.CustomUserCreationForm"   in settings.py. Now it started to work. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `blank=True` means that the users will not be required to fill out the value in *forms* and  `null=True` means that NULL values will be allowed in the DB level.

In this situation, maybe the best option will be to have `blank=False, null=True`–the latter for flexibility.